# Text Shadow Blurry when Printing

Tags: css, printing, shadow, blurry

So I require to have a text shadow (more like a border around the text which I create by using text-shadow) on my text, but the whole thing is with the focus of printing. At first I had the problem that the text-shadow wasn't rendered but after looking this up and using the following code:

```
@media print{
.p-progress h5{
    -webkit-filter: 
     drop-shadow(1px 0 0 #1e1f21)
     drop-shadow(-1px 0px 0 #1e1f21) 
     drop-shadow(0 1px 0 #1e1f21) 
     drop-shadow(0px -1px 0 #1e1f21);
}}
```

The text gets blurry when seen in the print preview:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this, or have some kind of text border working when printing?

Thanks in advance for further information.

Comment: Is that only happen in Chrome?

Comment: Yes in both Firefox and Chrome this is happening, and in Edge something weirder is happening... So yea quite problematic. Is there perhaps any other way to get a stroke around text?

Comment: No idea about others browser. But if that happening only chrome then I found an answer where they said chrome already fix that issue. But it seems they are not right though.

Comment: Please read full thread https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174583

Comment: Hmm interesting, then I might need to find another way to add this... sadly enough because it was a proper way to display it!